# Unusual error in setkeyv with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd consdier myself very familiar with `data.table`, but have encountered a strange error in the `setkeyv` function that I can't sort out.

The error is very straightforward:

```
keycols<-c("A", "B")
DT <- data.table(A=1:10, B=91:90)
setkeyv(DT, keycols)
# Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
#   4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

For reference, this is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] cvTools_0.3.2     robustbase_0.92-4 lattice_0.20-31   kernlab_0.9-20    rstan_2.6.0       inline_0.3.14     Rcpp_0.11.6       data.table_1.9.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] chron_2.3-47   grid_3.2.0     plyr_1.8.3     stats4_3.2.0   magrittr_1.5   stringi_0.5-4  reshape2_1.4.1 tools_3.2.0    stringr_1.0.0 
[10] DEoptimR_1.0-2
```

Comment: I am also using R 3.2.0 and data.table 1.9.4 and it works fine for me. Maybe some of your other packages are making trouble.

Comment: `data.table` 1.9.4 was working fine for me with R 3.2.0.  Then I started getting a weird error with ggplot and a data.table (something about failing to initialize a loop). I selectively updated packages, then `data.table` stopped working. It felt like something got corrupted. Upgrading to R 3.2.1 fixed my problem too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have no explanation for why this is the case, but upgrading to R 3.2.1 and installing the latest version of every package resolves the issue. For reference, this is my `sessionInfo()` after updating:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] kernlab_0.9-20    rstan_2.6.0       inline_0.3.14     Rcpp_0.11.6       cvTools_0.3.2     robustbase_0.92-4 lattice_0.20-31   data.table_1.9.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] chron_2.3-47   grid_3.2.1     plyr_1.8.3     stats4_3.2.1   magrittr_1.5   stringi_0.5-4  reshape2_1.4.1 tools_3.2.1    stringr_1.0.0 
[10] DEoptimR_1.0-2
```

Comment: seems that the problem was in `nchar` function. Point 3 in [new features](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-3.2.1.html)

Comment: +1 This was from June 2015 with v1.9.4, before v1.9.6 was on CRAN in Sep 2015.  I tested v1.9.6 with the stated dependency (R 2.14.1) so I think as long as you have 1.9.6 it should work before and after the nchar change in R 3.2.1 that @AndriyT. points to.  I added [#1370](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1370) to double check the setkeyv tests.

Comment: Proposed explanation added here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32959306/403310  but I'm not sure.  Thanks to hint from @AndriyT. above.

Comment: @MattDowle, thank's for a wider explanation, good answer. Btw it seems that the link in my comment doesn't exists now. Here is the [similar one](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-3-2-1-is-released/)

Comment: @AndriyT. Sure. Here's the stable link from cran ('What's new?' link on CRAN homepage):  https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html