# Error when trying to use xgb.importance in r from xgboost package

Tags: r, xgboost

I have trained a model using `xgb.train` from the `xgboost` package using R. I am trying to get the importance of the features for this model. I am getting the following error constantly:

```
Error in fread(paste(longString, collapse = ""), sep = "\n", header = F) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

I share my code here in case it helps:

```
# Make the xgb.DMatrix
train <- sparse.model.matrix(TARGET ~ ., data = train)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=train, label=train.y)

# Set the desired parameters
myParams <- list(objective           = "binary:logistic", 
                 booster             = "gbtree",
                 eval_metric         = "auc",
                 eta                 = 0.02,
                 max_depth           = 5,
                 min_child_weight    = 12,
                 gamma               = 0.1,
                 subsample           = 0.7,
                 colsample_bytree    = 0.7)

# Train model
myXGBfit <- xgb.train(params              = myParams, 
                      data                = dtrain, 
                      nrounds             = 369, 
                      verbose             = 1,
                      watchlist           = watchlist,
                      maximize            = FALSE)

# Calculate feature importance matrix
importance <- xgb.importance(feature_names = train@Dimnames[[2]], model = myXGBfit)
```

I have tried using `xgboost` instead of `xgb.train` to train the model but I get the same error when trying to get the feature importance matrix. I have also read the documentation for the `xgboost` package and searched online for help but was unable to find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

If it's of any use, `sessionInfo()` provides the following information:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pROC_1.8      Matrix_1.2-4  xgboost_0.4-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] plyr_1.8.3       magrittr_1.5     tools_3.2.0      yaml_2.1.13      Rcpp_0.12.3     
 [6] stringi_1.0-1    grid_3.2.0       knitr_1.12.3     data.table_1.9.6 stringr_1.0.0   
[11] chron_2.3-47     lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error and also running on R 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved after updating the R version from 3.2.0 to 3.2.4 Revised. Running the `version` command produces the following info:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32                         
arch           x86_64                                     
os             mingw32                                    
system         x86_64, mingw32                            
status         Revised                                    
major          3                                          
minor          2.4                                        
year           2016                                       
month          03                                         
day            16                                         
svn rev        70336                                      
language       R                                          
version.string R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
nickname       Very Secure Dishes
```

To update the R version, I used the `installr` package and I run the `updateR()` command (only available for Windows) from the R GUI. Hope it helps anybody in my same situation!

Answer (score 4):

This usually works for me:

```
importance <- xgb.importance(dimnames(train)[[2]], model = myXGBfit)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work out. I still get the same error: `Error in fread(paste(longString, collapse = ""), sep = "\n", header = F) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3`. I tried typing only `dimnames(train)[[2]]` and works just fine. I don't know what's the issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Could you try upgrading to the latest R version? I found another thread saying there's a problem with R version 3.2.0, which you seem to be running, with a similar error message. The latest version, 3.2.4, might work better. Here's the info I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912268/error-in-r-data-table-v1-9-6-function-fread